# How to find substrings of length m that contain ith element(C#)

Tags: c#, string, indexing, substring

We have a string length of `n`, I want to find all substrings of length `m` that contain `i`th element.

For example `string s = "abcde";` I want to get all substrings of length `3` that contain `2`nd element i.e. `"b"`, in this case

> abc, bcd

that is 2. But how we can code this for a general situation, i.e. substrings of length `m`, from a string of length `n`, that contain `i`th element

**It would be good if substrings are stored in `List<string>`(not just `Console.WriteLine()`)**

Comment: What is the problem to loop from `i-m` to `i`?

Comment: let's say I have a string with 50 symbols and want to get a substring of length 10 that contains the 34th element what you say works just for 24-34 substring, but I need 34-44 and all substrings with start index 25-33 to end index 35-43

Comment: So what is the problem to loop from 25 to 33, each time taking a string that starts at that number and goes for 10 characters?

Comment: I realized that when you wrote your first comment, but this is related to a bigger problem and there are more conditions than in this question, anyway, now I have an idea to deal with this,  thank you. I'll post the answer when the problem get solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static List<string> GetSubStrings_i(string inputString, int mainIndex, int sbstrLength)
        {
            List<string> substringsList = new List<string>();


            for (int i = mainIndex - sbstrLength + 1; i <= mainIndex; i++)
            {
                if (i < 0)
                    i = 0;

                if (i + sbstrLength <= inputString.Length)                                      
                    substringsList.Add(inputString.Substring(i, sbstrLength));
                
            }
                return substringsList;

        }
```

**"*"** is a symbol that all substrings should contain

### Input

- String = fsaf*faj;aijefaejsk
- substrLength = 5
- Index = 4

### Output

- substring = fsaf*
- substring = saf*f
- substring = af*fa
- substring = f*faj
- substring = *faj;

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

First you call `getAllSubstrings`, return list of all substrings of length `m` that contain `i th` element

`List<String> matchsubstring = getAllSubstrings("abcde","b");`

```
  public static List<String> getAllSubstrings(String inputString, String stringmatch)
  {
    List<String> resultList = new List<String>();
    
    for(int j = 0; j < inputString.Length; j++)
    {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < inputString.Length - j + 1 ;i++)
        {
            if(inputString.Substring(i,j).Contains(stringmatch))
            {
                resultList.Add(inputString.Substring(i,j));
                Console.WriteLine("Substring Length : "+j +
                        ", Substring :" + inputString.Substring(i,j) +
                        ", Index of string match :"+ inputString.Substring(i,j).IndexOf(stringmatch.ToCharArray()[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return resultList;
  }
```

Then you call `getAllMatchSubstringByIndexing` , return list of all substrings of length `m` that contain `i th` element at `x` index

`List<String> outputList = getAllMatchSubstringByIndexing (matchsubstring ,"b",1)`

`matchsubstring` is output of getAllSubstrings function

```
public static List<String> getAllMatchSubstringByIndexing(List<string> substring, String stringmatch, int index)
{
  List<String> substringWithIndex = new List<String>();
  foreach(var substringData in substring)
  {
      if(substringData.IndexOf(stringmatch.ToCharArray()[0]) == index)
      {
          substringWithIndex.Add(substringData);
          Console.WriteLine("Output : "+substringData);
      }
  }
  return substringWithIndex;
}
```

Comment: stringmatch is not necessary, I need the size of the substring, the index of the element that the substring should contain, and get all substrings that have an element with particular index

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Check my answer above